# Name of an effect, negative amplification

Tags: social-psychology

I've read several times about an effect that turns up when you are in a conversation with a person and the person starts suddenly complaining about their job, hobby or relationship.

If one confirms their negative views on the topic, they change into a defensive position and start defending what they criticized before. If one does the opposite, they turn even more negative towards their complaints.

Has this an name?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Can you please [edit] to give an example link to what you have read about these conversations?